# How can we perform an action when as switch is changed in a TableView List?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Our application displays a list of category groups:

```cs
List<CategoryGroupWordCountVM> categoryGroups;
```

On the screen it looks something like this:

> Sports      23   [Switch on]
>
> Hobbies      5   [Switch on]
>
> Countries   55   [Switch on]
>
> Occupations  0   [Switch off]

The rows objects like this:

```cs
public class CategoryGroupWordCountVM : ObservableProperty {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsToggled { get; set; }
}
```

Page XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"        x:Class="Japanese.CategoryGroupPage" x:Name="CategoryGroupPage">
   <ContentPage.Content>
      <TableView x:Name="tableView" Intent="Settings">
      </TableView>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Row XAML:

```xml
<ViewCell 
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   x:Class="Japanese.MyViewCell">
   <Grid>
      <Label Text = "{Binding Name}" />
      <Label Text = "{Binding TotalWordCount}" />
      <Switch IsToggled = "{Binding IsToggled}" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Backing C#

```cs
protected void RefreshPage() {
   categoryGroups = App.DB.GetCategoryGroupWithWordCount();
   var section = new TableSection("Available Categories");
   foreach (var category in categoryGroups) {
      var cell = new MyViewCell { BindingContext = category };
  section.Add(cell);
   }
   tableView.Root.Add(section);
}

protected override void OnAppearing() {
   base.OnAppearing();
   RefreshPage();
}
```

What we would like to do is have it so that when a user switches the toggle a method like the following is called and the value of TotalWordCount for the row where the switch changed is updated.

```cs
void selectCategoryGroup(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) {
   if (e.SelectedItem == null) {
      return;
   }
   var categoryGroup = (CategoryGroupWordCountVM)e.SelectedItem;
   App.DB.UpdateCategoryGroupIsToggled(categoryGroup.IsToggled, categoryGroup.Id);
   // The row that follows needs to update the value so that 
   // the screen shows a new value for on the left side of 
   // the switch. When the switch is off this will always be
   // 0. When on it will be the list of words in the category
   TotalWordCount = GetWordCountForCategory(categoryGroup.Id);
}
```

This was previously implemented by adding this code `

```cs
<ListView ItemSelected="selectCategoryGroup" >
```

But now we are using a TableView we don’t have this.

So we would very much appreciate if anyone could give some advice on how to could trigger a method like selectCategoryGroup when the switches are changed.

Note that typically there will be about 20-30 different entries in the categoryGroups list. Also if it would make it easier then I would be happy if the MyViewCell was coded in C#.

Comment: Why do you create the TableView  again after change the switch ?? You would like to operate db according to the toggled switch , it's no problem, but  it is no need to call the method RefreshPage(), since the view has already changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Updated 08/21:*** *Restructured answer a bit and added cleanup code; Added another solution based on property changed event*

### Option 1 - Use custom event

In order to handle switch's `Toggled` event at parent `TableView` level; you will need to propagate the event up to parent viewcell. One of the ways to do that would be to expose an event in your custom `MyViewCell`.

**Steps:**

1. Declare event in your custom viewcell (code-behind).

   ```
   public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> SelectedOrToggled;
   ```
2. Assign `Toggled` event-handler for switch defined in viewcell's XAML

   ```
   <ViewCell 
       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
       x:Class="Japanese.MyViewCell">
       <Grid>
           <Label Text = "{Binding Name}" />
           <Label Text = "{Binding TotalWordCount}" />
           <Switch IsToggled = "{Binding IsToggled}" Toggled="Handle_Toggled" />
       </Grid>
   ```
3. And invoke your custom event in it (in control's code-behind)

   ```
   void Handle_Toggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
   {
       var view = sender as BindableObject;
       SelectedOrToggled?.Invoke(this, new 
       SelectedItemChangedEventArgs(view.BindingContext));
   }
   ```
4. **Usage:** You can now subscribe to custom event in parent-page where you use/instantiate your custom viewcell.

   ```
   //XAML usage
   //<local:MyViewCell SelectedOrToggled="selectCategoryGroup" />

   protected void RefreshPage()
   {
       categoryGroups = App.DB.GetCategoryGroupWithWordCount();
       var section = new TableSection("Available Categories");
       foreach (var category in categoryGroups)
       {
           var cell = new MyViewCell { BindingContext = category };
           // assign method as event-handler
           cell.SelectedOrToggled += selectCategoryGroup;
           section.Add(cell);
       }
       tableView.Root.Add(section);
   }
   ```
5. **Cleanup:** To avoid memory leaks, it is recommend that you unsubscribe during unload.

   ```
   protected override void OnDisappearing()
   {
       base.OnDisappearing();

       foreach (var section in tableView.Root)
       {
           foreach(var cell in section)
           {
               cell.Tapped -= openCategoriesPage;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

*Selection behavior:* You can further customize this by handling `Tapped` event in `ViewCell` and raise `SelectedOrToggled` event (similar to Handle_Toggled) in order to mimic `ListView` selection behavior.

### Option 2 - Use `PropertyChanged` event in view-model

You can listen to `IsToggled` property change in `CategoryGroupWordCountVM` and react accordingly.

**Steps:**

1. **Usage:** You can subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event in viewmodel.

   ```
   protected void RefreshPage()
   {
       categoryGroups = App.DB.GetCategoryGroupWithWordCount();
       var section = new TableSection("Available Categories");
       foreach (var category in categoryGroups)
       {
           var cell = new MyViewCell { BindingContext = category };
           // assign method as event-handler
           cat.PropertyChanged += CategoryVM_PropertyChanged;
           section.Add(cell);
       }
       tableView.Root.Add(section);
   }

   async void CategoryVM_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       if(e.PropertyName == nameof(CategoryGroupWordCountVM.IsToggled))
       {
           var categoryGroup = (CategoryGroupWordCountVM)sender;
           ...//call update code here
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Cleanup:** To avoid memory leaks, it is recommend that you unsubscribe during unload.

   ```
   protected override void OnDisappearing()
   {
       base.OnDisappearing();

       foreach (var section in tableView.Root)
       {
           foreach(var cell in section)
           {
               (cell as ObservableProperty)?.PropertyChanged -= CategoryVM_PropertyChanged;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your very good answer.  I opened up a bounty for this question as a show of appreciation and accepted your answer.  I (or another in the small group I work in) may be having more questions such as this and very much appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Thanks :) - happy to know this answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe **Toggled** event of Switch which is raised when **Switch** is toggled.

Comment: Can you give an example.  Thanks